# Titanium appcelerator animate view blinks

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to animate a view when click corresponding button, unfortunately when animate from top to bottom view blink :

```
/*
* ANIMATE FROM BOTTOM TO TOP
*/
function showModal(item){
    var bottom_to_top = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        top : '0%',
        duration : 500
    });
    $[item].animate(bottom_to_top)
}

/*
* ANIMATE FROM TOP TO BOTTOM
*/
function hideModal(item){
    var top_to_bottom = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        top : '100%',
        duration : 500
    });
    $[item].animate(top_to_bottom)
}

///// HERE I SHOW HIDE MY VIEW
function button_show(){
    showModal($.myView);
}
function button_hide(){
    hideModal($.myView);
}
```

First problem, if i assign "100%" to hide view, it's not appear when i try to show, only value 99 and below works.
Second problem, animation blinks when hide view.

Someone could tell what i should do please? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid percentage margins as often as possible. Also, use native technologies to show a modal window, e.g.

```js
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "My Modal Window",
    backgroundColor: "white"
});

var nav = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: window
});

nav.open({
    modal: true
});
```